# Pairwise comparison of columns for selecting rows in case both rows are not zero

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset

consider the following matrix/data.frame and vector:

```
set.seed(123)
data<-data.frame(lorem=floor(runif(26, min=0, max=10)),
                    ipsum=floor(runif(26, min=0, max=10)),
                        dolor=floor(runif(26, min=0, max=10)))

topicVector<-c(1,2,12,13,14,15,18,22,23,31 ,36 ,40 ,44 
             ,54,58,59,73,100,101,104,107,108,111,113,114,116)
```

Note: `topicVector` could also be part of `data` as they are of equal length.

My goal is to do a pairwise comparison of all unique combinations of columns from `data` and convert it into a long data.frame which lists all numbers from `topicVector` which serves as an index for non-zero rows that the columns in `data` share.

I.e. each row in the result data.frame should be one possible combination of columns: e.g. `lorem` and `ipsum` from `data`. The number in `topics` refers to the rows which they both have non zero entries in `data` and comes from `topicVector`.
Let's look at `lorem` and ìpsum`from`data`(the first combination)

```
      lorem ipsum 
1      2     5     
2      7     5     
3      4     2     
4      8     1     
5      9     9     
6      0     9     
7      5     6     
8      8     7     
9      5     0     
10     4     4     
11     9     7     
12     4     2     
13     6     3     
14     5     2     
15     1     1     
16     8     4     
17     2     4     
18     0     3     
19     3     1     
20     9     1     
21     8     2     
22     6     4     
23     6     2     
24     9     8     
25     6     0     
26     7     4
```

In the example above for `lorem` and `ipsum` the rows 1, 2 and 3 contain both numbers i.e. shared topics. According to the topic vector this are topics 1,2 and 12. In row 4 ipsum is 0 thus they don't share this topic and topic 13 is not part of the result data.frame.
In total they share multiple topics (18).

In case no topic is shared (i.e. all rows=0) `topics` in the result df should contain 0 for this pair of columns.

The outcome of the above should look like this:

```
     user1 user2 topics
1  lorem ipsum      1
2  lorem ipsum      2
3  lorem ipsum     12
4  lorem ipsum     13
5  lorem ipsum     14
6  lorem ipsum     18
7  lorem ipsum     22
8  lorem ipsum     31
9  lorem ipsum     36
10 lorem ipsum     40
11 lorem ipsum     44
12 lorem ipsum     54
13 lorem ipsum     58
14 lorem ipsum     59
15 lorem ipsum     73
16 lorem ipsum    101
17 lorem ipsum    104
18 lorem ipsum    107
19 lorem ipsum    108
20 lorem ipsum    111
21 lorem ipsum    113
22 lorem ipsum    116
23 lorem dolor      1
24 lorem dolor      2
25 lorem dolor     12
26 lorem dolor     13
27 lorem dolor     14
28 lorem dolor     18
29 lorem dolor     22
30 lorem dolor     23
31 lorem dolor     36
32 lorem dolor     40
33 lorem dolor     44
34 lorem dolor     54
35 lorem dolor     58
36 lorem dolor     59
37 lorem dolor     73
38 lorem dolor    101
39 lorem dolor    104
40 lorem dolor    107
41 lorem dolor    111
42 lorem dolor    113
43 lorem dolor    114
44 lorem dolor    116
45 ipsum dolor      1
46 ipsum dolor      2
47 ipsum dolor     12
48 ipsum dolor     13
49 ipsum dolor     14
50 ipsum dolor     15
51 ipsum dolor     18
52 ipsum dolor     22
53 ipsum dolor     36
54 ipsum dolor     40
55 ipsum dolor     44
56 ipsum dolor     54
57 ipsum dolor     58
58 ipsum dolor     59
59 ipsum dolor     73
60 ipsum dolor    100
61 ipsum dolor    101
62 ipsum dolor    104
63 ipsum dolor    107
64 ipsum dolor    111
65 ipsum dolor    113
66 ipsum dolor    116
```

I wrote a function in R which does the job. HOWEVER the original data is slightly bigger (1000 columns) and `listCommonTopics` is very slow.

```
listCommonTopics<-function(data,topicVector){
  result_df<-data.frame(user1=character(),
                        user2=character(),
                        topics=numeric(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(i in seq_along(data)){
    print(i)
    for(j in seq_along(data)){
      if(j>i){
          if(colnames(data[i])!=colnames(data[j])){
              compareUsers<-data.frame(topicVector,data[,i],data[,j],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
              commonTopics<-subset(compareUsers,compareUsers[,2]!=0&compareUsers[,3]!=0)
            if(nrow(commonTopics)==0){ 
               user1<-rep(colnames(data[i]),1)
               user2<-rep(colnames(data[j]),1)
               topics<-0
            }else{
              user1<-rep(colnames(data[i]),nrow(commonTopics))
              user2<-rep(colnames(data[j],nrow(commonTopics)))
              topics<-commonTopics[,1]
            }
        pairwise_df<-data.frame(user1=user1,user2=user2,topics=topics,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        result_df<-rbind(result_df,pairwise_df)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(result_df)  
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why is my version THAT slow? I know nested for-loops are not the
   best idea, but even after several hours I had no result.
2. What would a vectorised matrix version (apply) look like?
3. Could it also been done using `dplyr`?

Comment: Please explain how the output is derived from the input in more details. You explanation is insufficient to derive an algorithm.

Comment: Apparently I still don't get it. The fourth row does not contain a zero. This I thought "lorum ipsum 13" should be in the result. But it isn't.

Comment: Sorry for being not precise enough ... I gave it another try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(combn(names(data), 2, simplify = FALSE),
               function(x) {
                 test <- Reduce("*", data[, x]) != 0
                 data.frame(setNames(as.list(x), c("user1", "user2")), 
                                      topics = if (any(test)) topicVector[test] else 0)
                 })
)
```

This

- creates all combinations of column names in a list,
- iterates over that list,
- checks if the product (calculated with a `Reduce("*", inputList)` construct) of the two columns is zero and uses this for subsetting the topics vector,
- combines the results with the `do.call(rbind, listOfResults)` construct.

Comment: I  - again - updated the two columns and the result based on the reproducible example ... now you should be able to get the same df... 
I also tried your code ... I think it breaks on situations where both rows contain 0 ... however your suggestion made me identify the bottleneck which seems to be the rbind so  kudos for  do.call(rbind,lapply())

Comment: But could you elaborate on what the Reduce("*") does?

Comment: I've added an `if` condition for the zero rows case.